# Checklist Box (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

My query is quite simple yet complex for me!!

The scenario is that I have a checklist box whose checked items are to be added in a listbox for further processing. All I need to know is how to uncheck an item in a checklist box if an item is removed from the listbox. There are two buttons named `Remove All` and `Remove Selected Item` (from the items selected in the Listbox).

Please help me with the functioning of the second button, i.e. if a user removes a particular item from the listbox, the corresponding chechklist item also should get unchecked.

Guide me as to how to uncheck a particular item in the checklist I removed from listbox.

Comment: Use jquery to easilly manage controls in client side

Comment: You may want to edit your question and post some relevant code to help people give you better answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to uncheck the item from the server side you can do something like this:

```
yourCheckBoxList.Items.FindByValue(itemValue).Selected = false;
```

If you wish to delete the checkboxlist item:

```
yourCheckBoxList.Items.Remove(yourCheckBoxList.Items.FindByValue(itemValue));
```

where *itemValue* is a string where you need to store the value of the item removed from the listbox.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery, when you click on remove button then pickup the seleced value from the list, find that value in checkbox list and unchecked with
$('#checkedboxId').removeAttr('checked')

Comment: It's not as simple as that, especially with ASP.NET because the control ids will get changed. To get the correct ID you can use the ClientIDMode="Static" attribute on the control in .NET 4 or use the jQuery "ends with" syntax - see http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: put you checkbox id in an javascript object or in hidden control like this. hdnCheckBoxId.value = <%CheckboxId.ClientID%>; then you can read id from hidden control and make it un checked. $('#hdnCheckBoxId').removeAttr('checked');